# Как получить знак Глас народа?

Tags: обсуждение, поддержка, знаки

Для его получения нужно использовать 40 голосов за 24 часа. Я израсходовал 30 голосов. Как получить дополнительные 10 голосов?

Comment: Не надо только голосовать за что попало. Это накрутка.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Вы голосовали, вероятно, по большей части за ответы. Вот и израсходовали 30 голосов.

Вы сможете проголосовать 40 раз за день и получить знак только в том случае, если 10 ваших голосов было за вопросы. Если вы голосуете только за ответы, то упрётесь в лимит 30 голосов.

Comment: Не большая часть, а хотя бы 10.

Comment: @Qwertiy могу уже путать. Спасибо)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но к сожалению не могу проголосовать) Но завтра обязательно отблагодарю голосом)

Comment: @Circassian Accept.

Comment: @VictorVosMottorthanksMonica Спасибо что напомнили!